# How can I parent an object to a camera?

Tags: tracking, .fbx

I have a scene set up where I render animations.  For most of my character renders, my current setup is fine, but some of the more active animations make the subject figure leave the borders of the camera, disappearing from the shot for a while.  I would normally have the camera track to a part of the character's anatomy, but I've changed my setup to include square with a logo that should be in the same position in front of the camera.

How can I get the square to maintain exactly the same position, distance, and rotation relative to the camera while the camera is tracking another object?

Comment: Not sure if i understood you correctly. A fairly simple way is to use 'Child Of' constraint on the "Square" with the 'Target Object' set to "Camera".

Comment: ...or you can just select your square, shift select your camera, CTRL-P -> keep offset

Comment: The phrasing of the title suggests you know what parenting is... so short answer is, you parent an object to a camera the same way like you parent it to any other object.

Comment: I think this was a good example of me assuming it would be far more difficult than it actually was.  Thanks, folks!